# What does DT_WHT means in /usr/include/dirent.h ?

Tags: linux, file-type, dirent.h

I am reading the source code of the dirent.h
there's a enum

```
enum
{
    DT_UNKNOWN = 0,  // unknown type
    #define DT_UNKNOWN DT_UNKNOWN
    DT_FIFO = 1,     // a named pipe, or FIFO
    #define DT_FIFO DT_FIFO
    DT_CHR = 2,     // a character device
    #define DT_CHR DT_CHR
    DT_DIR = 4,     // a directory
    #define DT_DIR DT_DIR
    DT_BLK = 6,     // a block device
    #define DT_BLK DT_BLK
    DT_REG = 8,     // regular file
    #define DT_REG DT_REG
    DT_LNK = 10,    // symbolic link
    #define DT_LNK DT_LNK
    DT_SOCK = 12,   // local domain socket
    #define DT_SOCK DT_SOCK
    DT_WHT = 14     // ?
    #define DT_WHT DT_WHT
};
```

SO what is DT_WHT?
I've searched the Single Unix Specification Version 4, and got nothing.
My distro is CentOS 6.2 x64
Linux Kernel Version is: 2.6.32-220.x16.x86_64.

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/39826/what-does-whiteout-mean-in-a-copy-on-write-filesystem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I googled `readdir DT_WHT` and found [this thread](http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/BZ-6895-Describe-DT-LNK-td5495.html) which explains that it's a "whiteout" from BSD.

Answer (score 0):

In a layered filesystem, an upper layer may contain "whiteout" inodes to hide files from lower layer.

`DT_WHT` inode type is [supported but ignored in Linux kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/DT_WHT). This is also documented in man page [rename(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html):

> BSD union mount employs a separate inode type, DT_WHT, which, while supported by some filesystems available in Linux, such as CODA and XFS, is ignored by the kernel's whiteout support code, as of Linux 4.19, at least.